# How do fictional names get their genders?

Tags: gender

Like in "Star Wars: Die Rache der Sith"
Sith is feminine why?

Comment: Is it? I don’t think so, and from the example we cannot tell, because it is plural.

Comment: Welome here, FallenHero! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. You may improve your question with an [edit] and the help of [ask].

Comment: Für einen Nichttrekkie ist das nicht offensichtlich. "Die Rache der Ruth" wäre ok, und wirklich feminin, auch wenn "Ruths Rache" wohl von den meisten bevorzugt würde, schon wg. der Alliteration.

Comment: Trekkie? *facepalm*

Comment: It isn't female. It is plural. It is like »Die Rache der Briten« or, to make it even clearer »Die Rache der Männer«.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Der` is **plural** in that case not *feminine*, and the gender information is automatically lost with the German article.

Applied for individuals `der Sith` or `die Sith` could be used gender specific:

> **Der** Sith, der meinen Vater getötet hat.

---

> **Die** Sith, die meinen Sohn geboren hat.

Note the recurring article for these cases of use.

Worth to mention, that *"Sith"* is used in the Star Wars universe to attribute a group of people, and not a particular individuum('s name).

Comment: I find the imagination, which lets a sith to give birth to your son, is hilarious. I am still laughing at it.